# Navigating between parental panels

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have problems with editing panels in C# windows forms(Visual studio 2008). I placed some panels into another, and now I have problems with navigating panels inside parental containers. Is there any tool that gives not only drag-drop control, but also tree view of container and panels in it. For example, like Navigator window in NetBeans(IDE for Java). Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about VS2008, but newer versions have Document Outline Window (View > Other Windows > Document Outline)

Comment: Thanks. There is such window in VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

To not get lost in controls, consider to name them properly. Then you can find them in the list of *Properties* window.

Instead of `label1` use `labelInputName`, located on `panel1`, which you also rename to `panelInput`. This gives parent/child feeling and you will never lost.

If you get lost, use *Document Outline* window to see tree-like relation via `Controls` property (who is control of who). This window is a helper (help to find and select control), you will still have to use designer to do changes.

Another important thing is UI design. Whenever you get *cluttered* or *bulky* feeling, than it's the time to change something.

Making `UserControl` for repeatable part is one way.

Another is to **differ *design* and *run* time** (what you see in designer): to example, if you have several panels, which has to be shown at same place, then you can use *dynamic* container for them (`FlowLayoutPanel`, `TableLayoutPanel`) **or** you can have them placed in a way for you to easily see them in design-time, but their position will be corrected during run-time (to example, in the constructor). Prioritizing designing is a must if you are going to support project and edit functionality in next versions.

p.s.: talking about winforms, but all said should be true for wpf  as well.